# Es posible llamar a una funcion de un componente de angular mediante una directiva?

Tags: angular, componentes, viewchild

Lo que pretendo hacer  es que cuando exista una interseccion en la seccion de about mi menu se marque de un color en esa misma seccion. Intento hacer dos funciones en componente header para que me cambie el color y las llamo en la directiva , pero al momento de ejecutar las funciones changeRed y changeBlue me marca el error  "TypeError: this.renderer is undefined". Alguien sabe porque?, soy una novata en programacion y me yudaria mucho si me pueden apoyar con esto

**Este es el codigo de mi directiva**

```
import {

  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  Renderer2,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  ViewChild,
  ViewChildren,
  QueryList,
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ComponentRef,

} from '@angular/core';

import { HeaderComponent } from '../header/header.component';
import { AboutComponent } from 'src/app/pages/about/about.component';
@Directive({
  selector: '[fadeIn]',
})

export class FadeInDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() thresholdMax = 1;
  @Input() thresholdMin = 0.1;
  @Output() isVisible = new EventEmitter<string>();

  //buton: any

  @ViewChild('HeaderComponent', { static: false }) headerComponent = HeaderComponent;
  @ViewChild('AboutComponent', { static: false }) aboutComponent = AboutComponent;

  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private header: HeaderComponent
  ) {

  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createObserver();
  }

  addClassName(className: any) {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.element.nativeElement, className);
    this.isVisible.emit();
  }

  removeClassName(className: any) {
    if (
      this.element.nativeElement.classList.contains(className)
    ) {
      this.renderer.removeClass(
        this.element.nativeElement, className
      );
    }
  }

  createObserver() {
    const options = {
      threshold: [this.thresholdMin],
    };

    const callback = (entries: any) => {
      entries && entries.forEach((entry: any) => {
        console.log(entry.intersectionRatio)

        if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {

          this.addClassName('visible');

          //AQUI MANDO LLAMAR LA FUCNION DE MI COMPONENTE HEADER
          this.header.changeBlue()

        } else {
          this.removeClassName('visible');

          //AQUI MANDO LLAMAR LA OTRA FUCNION DE MI COMPONENTE HEADER
          this.header.changeRed()

        }
      });
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
    const target = this.element.nativeElement;
    target && observer.observe(target);

  }
}
```

**Este el codigo de mi componente .ts**

```
import { 
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  Renderer2,
  ViewChild,
  ViewChildren
} from '@angular/core';
import { FadeInDirective } from '../prueba/fade-in.directive';
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})


export class HeaderComponent {

  @ViewChild('btn', { static: true }) buttonRef?: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

  }

  public changeRed() {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.buttonRef.prototype.nativeElement, "resaltar");

  }

  public changeBlue() {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.buttonRef.nativeElement, "deresaltar");

  }

}
```

este es mi codigo de componente html

```
<section id="head">
  <div class="cont">
    <mat-toolbar class="menu">
      <div id="contmenu">
        <button mat-button class="optionMenu">Email</button>
        <button mat-button class="optionMenu">Github</button>
        <button mat-button class="optionMenu">Linkedin</button>
        <button mat-button class="optionMenu"></button>
        <button mat-button class="optionMenu"> <a href="#about">Portafolio</a></button>
        <button #btn routerLink="about" routerLinkActive="active">about</button>


        <button mat-button class="optionMenu point"
          routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active"
          [routerLinkActiveOptions]={exact:true}>.</button>

<!--
         <button (click)="goDown1()" mat-button class="optionMenu"
          routerLink="about" routerLinkActive="active">about</button>
        <button [ngClass]="newValue == 0 ? 'resaltar' : 'deresaltar'" mat-button
          class="optionMenu point" routerLink="/"
          routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]={exact:true}>.</button>

        <button mat-button class="optionMenu point" routerLink="/"
          routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]={exact:true}>.</button>
-->

      </div>

      <div class="contpre">

        <h1 id="hello">Hola<strong id="point">.</strong></h1>
        <span id="name" class="line">
          Soy Programadora Web
        </span>

        <div id="conthello">
          <button mat-raised-button id="raised" class="btn btn1">
            Ver CV
          </button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- <span class="material-icons">auto_awesome</span>
          <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon> -->
  </div>

</section>
<app-about [about]="3" [childMessage]="parentMessage"></app-about>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado!!, solo agregue el render en el el constructor del componente header.

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2,private el: ElementRef  ) {
   
}
```

Una vez terminado se los comparto para si a alguien le es de utilidad.